# Using rich datascroller With Hibernate Pagination on Server

Tags: hibernate, spring, richfaces

I am having rich:datatable having 500(row) data and I am using rich:datascroller for pagination but the problem is all the data are fetched on 1st time, so if anybody having a way that click on page 2 hibernate fetches rows from table (11-20). I am using Spring+Hibernate. Please Give solution in detail.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a custom data model and a custom data provider. The Data provider will take care of fetching limited results, using `query.setMaxResults(..)`. Note that since you are using spring, it would be good if your `DataProvider` instance is spring-managed.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707897/richfaces-extendedtabledatamodel-sorting-columns-retrieves-all-rows/3734654#3734654) is some code that we used for that purpose.

Comment: Ya bozho spring manages hibernate. I m not getting from the Solution given by the link. I can use Projection for rowCount() ? . But then also i m lil bit confused....

Comment: @taher - you can use whatever you like in your `DataProvider` implementation. Just copy the data model, and create a new `DataProvider` implementation. Its methods are straightforward to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own data scroller analogy with one task : to render via ajax the table U are  using for records displaying !

e.g.

```
<rich:dataTable id="dtId" rows="10" value="#{bean.records}" var="record">
       // content (records)
</rich:dataTable>
```

your own scroller:

```
   <a4j:repeat value="#{bean.pages}" var="page">
     <a4j:commandLink value="#{page}" render="dtId" 
           actionListener="#{bean.myListener()}">
        <f:param name="selectedPageNumber" value="#{page}" />
     </a4j:commandLink>
     </a4j:repeat>
```

you will get a table and smth. like that after: 0 1 2 3 4 5 (#{bean.pages} - just numbers - means pages)
and with click on each link (0123...) your listener (myListener) can retrieve new portion of data from DB and update #{bean.**records**} list and after rerendering you will have a table with new data !